# Is there a need for and way to define this in css?

Tags: css, facepile

This code is part of a facebook plugin called facepile and i was wondering if its possible and needed to define this code in css or leave it in the body as is?

```
data-width="200" data-height="64" data-max-rows="2" data-colorscheme="dark" data-size="medium" data-show-count="true"
```

Comment: The "data-" attributes are part of HTML5 and not CSS. So, to answer your questions no, and yes

Comment: examples: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/8ntfZ/

Comment: thanks il leave it as is i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the data-attribute with CSS with `[data-size]` for example, but it wouldn't make much sense in this case, as the attributes are used to define the options for the facebook plugin

So just leave it as it is, or if you want, change the attributes to your liking:

```
data-height="100"
```

This would probably make the facebook plugin higher.